# Designing for encapsulation

Tags: coding-style, encapsulation

I have a Office business object that has an officeId instance.

In business point of view, office ids can have 500 different values.

officeId =  1 means it is located in LA
officeId =  2 means it is located in SFO and so on

I want to check if office is for LA or SFO

I can have methods such as isOfficeInLosAngeles, isOfficeInSfo and so on

I can see this as a way to encapsulate data and behavior in Office.

But my concern is, I will have to add 500 is* methods to find out office.

Is there any way to extract these is* methods somewhere to simplify the design and still maintain encapsulation ?

Answer (score 1):

Design an enum with 500 values, one for each city.  Then, provide a `getCity` method that returns the city as one of the enum values.  Then your (Java language) check becomes

```
City c = office.getCity();
if (c == City.LA) {
    // Do something
} else if (c == City.SFO) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulation is right... think of it this way, where in your code should the "knowledge" that "1 means LA, 2 means SFO..." be encapsulated? If your office object is the only object that needs to know what the ID means, then you could expose a method `getOfficeLocation` that returns a useful representation, say a `String`, that callers of the `Office` object can use, knowing that interface won't change, even if you add new locations to a later version of the `Office` object.